# Word VBA: Store a reference to a specific selection (without using range)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to store a reference to a selection. It seems that I create a variable such as:

```
dim tSelect as Selection
Set tSelect = Selection
```

And I create a reference to the active selection object. If I change selection WITHOUT running any code (for instance, during a DoEvents type loop) the selection variable updates without calling:

```
Set tSelect = Selection
```

I need to create a variable that will hold a static reference to what is selected, then I need to be able to change selection without losing the reference to the previously selected text.

The Range object wont work. I need to be able to select a list of paragraphs using the ctrl key that are not necessarily near each other.

When using this method to select paragraphs, the selection object only shows the last "group" of paragraphs (for instance, if I select 1 paragraph, skip the next one and use ctrl+click to select 2 more, the range/selection objects only point at the last 2).

The following does not work either (for admittedly obvious reasons):

```
set tSelect = new selection
```

Any ideas would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to microsoft, this problem will have great difficulties.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288424

The best solution I can think of is changing the style of the text to something unique in the file, then search the file and create a collection of subranges for the unique text. Once you have the collection of subranges you can change the style back to normal.

In the link above, it says that you can not use vba to select multiple ranges. Which means that you'll have to use vba code to loop through the collection of sub ranges whenever you want to perform an action.

In recap, Storing:

1. Make text unique with one of the properties that does work with discontinguous selections
2. Loop through file, find chunks of unique text and store them as separate ranges in a collection
3. Loop through collection and make text normal again

Performing an action:

1. loop through collection of sub ranges
2. perform action on each subrange

Comment: This answeres my question but chances are I'm not going to use your method. This is solely because I can't change the font to anything that I can "gaurentee" is unique. I may find an alternative way to identify the text though. Tanks you for your research.

Comment: You could loop through the file once to determine a fontsize/fontstyle that is not in use, then do the above. Font size would be easier to work with. It's not academic perfection (there's a limit on font size), but I've never seen a doc file where it wouldn't get the job done.
Really, using size 1 font or anything obscure should work fine.

Comment: Couldn't you store (in Collection or Dictionary object) the beginning/end character of each range? I haven't tested this but I think it should avoid needing to manipulate the font size.

Comment: "Selection.Range" is incompatible with discontinguous selections. Which means that if you had multiple ranges selected, VBA only keeps track of information regarding the last one. There are only a few properties that are compatible with discontinguous selections, such as font size, and style.

Comment: Selection.font and selection.paragraph format objects work with  "discontinguous selections." David, there's no way to loop through the paragraphs individually as the selection object only views the last few paragraphs as valid options. selection.paragraphs(#) only refers to these paragraphs and selection.range.paragraphs does the same.

Comment: @Alter Unfortunately, in our documents, I cannot assume 1pt font size is not used; there are situations we use it. Furthermore, with the way that VBA read's font sizes, there's no guarantee that at the paragraph level, font sizes will be detectable; if a paragraph has multiple font sizes within it.